# How do you create a jQuery function with multiple .click() functions within it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How or, what is a good approach for this function i'm trying to create?

my_script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {


     $("#home").click(function() {
         $('.banner').animate({top:'370px', height:'250px', }, 1000)
         return false    
     })

     $("#about").click(function() {
         $('.banner').animate({top:'20px', height:'145px', }, 1000)
         return false
     })


     $("#games").click(function() {
         $('.banner').animate({top:'20px', height:'145px', }, 1000)
         return false
     })

     $("#district").click(function() {
         $('.banner').animate({top:'20px', height:'145px', }, 1000)
         return false
     })

     $("#contact").click(function() {
         $('.banner').animate({top:'20px', height:'145px', }, 1000)
         return false
     })


})
```

If an id in ["about","contact","district", "games", "membership"] - are clicked, i want to animate some stuff. But if id = "home", i want to animate (or don't animate if alreade on that page) it back.

Obviously, this code i posted doesen't work. But what kind of approach would you guys suggest? Should i put the id's for the banner to animate to the top of my page in an array and loop through it? (How does that look like) Or should i create many diffrent functions, one per id, like now?

/W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a common `class` instead of using `ids` except home, as you have same code for all items other then home.

```
$("#home").click(function() {
    $('.banner').animate({top:'370px', height:'250px', }, 1000)
     return false;    
});

$(".commonclassexcepthome").click(function() {
     $('.banner').animate({top:'370px', height:'250px', }, 1000)
     return false;    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
$("#home").click(function() {
     $('.banner').animate({top:'370px', height:'250px', }, 1000)
     return false;    
 });

 $("#about,#contact,#games,#district").click(function() {
     $('.banner').animate({top:'20px', height:'145px', }, 1000)
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I tried something similar before, but obv not the same since it didn't work then. :) Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

just make a function with parameters so when you click you call the function and give the parameters for the position and you simplify it

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TrVrN/) is a better way to write the code above.
You said that you do not want to animate `.banner` if you are already on that page ( or is this available only for home page? ) so the function will return false if the clicked item has `class="active"`

Note : i did not test the code because i don't have the rest of code.